# Moving the common angle to \pstVerb produces incorrect result

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

Consider the following complete code first.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}%
    \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def /CPX 1 def /CPY 0 def}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \xdef\points{\points(!1 Angles 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add dup /Angles ED PtoC %
        dup CPY add /CPY ED exch dup CPX add /CPX ED exch)(!CPX neg CPY neg)(!CPX CPY)}
    }
    \expandafter\psrline\points
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}%
    \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def /CPX 1 def /CPY 0 def}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \pstVerb{Angles 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add /Angles exch def}%
        \xdef\points{\points(!1 Angles PtoC %
        dup CPY add /CPY ED exch dup CPX add /CPX ED exch)(!CPX neg CPY neg)(!CPX CPY)}
    }
    \expandafter\psrline\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces two outputs as follows.

[image]

[image]

### Explanation

When I move the definition of `Angles` from

```
xdef\points{\points(!1 Angles 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add dup /Angles ED PtoC %
            dup CPY add /CPY ED exch dup CPX add /CPX ED exch)(!CPX neg CPY neg)(!CPX CPY)}
```

to

```
\pstVerb{Angles 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add /Angles exch def}
```

why does the output become incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally PostScript doesn't translate directly to TeX. Only `\space` and `\i` are properly identified and expanded.

When you include the `\pstVerb` inside the `\multido` loop, you are storing an updated version of `Angles` using PostScript. However, the construction of `\points` does not take this altered version of `Angles` into consideration, since it's not expanded in the usual TeX way. As such, the call

```
\expandafter\psrline\points
```

just uses the latest version of `Angles` when it does `\psrline` on the expanded `\points`.

Comment: +1 then is there any solution to overcome this limitation?

Comment: @CodeMocker: If you define `\Angles` using something like `pgfmath` or `fp`.

Comment: See my answer, I just got it by accident.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psset{linecolor=red}
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}%
    \pstVerb
    {
        /Angles 0 def
        /CPx 1 def 
        /CPy 0 def
        /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def
        /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def
    }
    \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
    {
        \xdef\points{\points(!1 \i\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)(!CPx neg CPy neg)(!CPx CPy)}
    }
    \expandafter\psrline\points
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```